# Javascript: Passing values to a function having array attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am sorry i am not a good in this, but
I want create a function like this

```
function show (message['head':'error','body':'msg'])
{ // 'error' and 'msg' and the default values
alert(message[head]);

}

show ({'head' : 'this is head', 'body' : 'this is body'});
```

What is the correct way to above method work properly ?

Comment: related or even a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10813852/concise-way-to-accept-an-options-object-as-an-argument-falling-back-to-defaults

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
function show (message)
{
    alert(message.head);
    // or
    alert(message['head']); // Note the quotes
}
```

Your call to it is fine.

To supply defaults, as [David points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14662097/157247), you can use the [curiously powerful `||` operator](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/javascripts-curiously-powerful-or.html):

```
function show (message)
{
    var head = message.head || 'error',
        body = message.body || 'msg';

    alert(head);
}
```

(The above is slightly different from David's approach in that it avoids changing the `message` object that was passed in, which is usually not a good idea as the function doesn't own the object, the caller does.)

That works because if `head` (for example) isn't on the `message` object at all, it's falsey, and so `head = message.head || 'error'` ends up assigning `'error'` to `head`. This is a handy trick, but there's a gotcha: If `head` could have a falsey value already, and that's valid, you don't want to use the `||` trick. Instead, you can use `in` to check:

```
function show (message)
{
    var head = 'head' in message ? message.head : 'error',
        body = 'body' in message ? message.body : 'msg';

    alert(head);
}
```

That will use the value from `message` if it's present, regardless of whether it's falsey.

Comment: `in` checks the prototype. Are you sure that's safe?

Comment: @David: I think it's appropriate here, yes. Otherwise we're in the odd position of using the default even though if we look at `message.head` we'd see a different value (if `message` is an object with `head` on its prototype). There's lots of places where you want `hasOwnProperty` instead, but to me, this isn't one of them.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for your help. But What should I do if I don't create 'new variable'.
For example:
message.head = 'head' in message ? message.head : 'error';

Comment: @ArhamAliQureshi: You can certainly do that (`message.head = 'head' in message ? message.head : 'error';`) if you like, just be aware that that's the kind of thing that can have unexpected side-effects (because you're modifying the `message` object that was passed to you). I've seen a *lot* of bugs over the years because people weren't expecting a function to modify something it received as an argument. Just be clear in your documentation of the function. But why wouldn't you use a variable? I'm not seeing the downside of doing that.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I tried that but I guess chrome is not letting me to do that. So I used you recommended technique.
I was trying to do that because I usually don't like to create multiple variables. But you are the Boss :)

Comment: @ArhamAliQureshi: Chrome doesn't have any problem with it: http://jsbin.com/ejiqet/1

Answer (score 1):

If an object doesn't have a property, access of that property will return the value `undefined`. We can use this along with the logical OR `||` operator to assign default values to the object.

```
function show(message) {
    message.head = message.head || 'error';
    message.body = message.body || 'msg';

    alert(message.head);
}
```

If `message.head` is undefined, it will assign `"error"` to the object property, or it will otherwise retain its value.

---

As Crower pointed out, this has a potential "gotcha" as an empty string can be deduced as a falsy value causing the unwanted assignment of a default value. Use this version as it checks if the property is actually on the object:

```
function show(message) {
    message.head = message.hasOwnProperty('head') ? message.head : 'error';
    message.body = message.hasOwnProperty('body') ? message.body : 'msg';

    alert(message.head);
}
```

Comment: +1 I missed the bit about default values. You might want to warn about the "gotcha" with regard to falsey property values (e.g., if `message.head` can meaningfully be `0` or `""`, you don't want to indiscriminately do `|| 'error'` on it).

Comment: Probably also worth mentioning that this *changes* the object passed in.

Answer (score 0):

Plesae examine [This](http://jsfiddle.net/SLePB/)

and mark the correct answer which satisfies you.

```
function show(message){
  alert(message['head']);
}
```